# in PHP what is the difference between + VS |

Tags: php

in PHP , what is the difference between (+) and (|) , consider the following example:-

```
<?php 
echo 1|2; //3
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: The `|` is a bitwise operator. Try this for example `echo 1|101;`

Comment: Completely different animal. `2|3` will output `3` as well. Don't use it for adding numbers together.